# 2 doors - one room - access control

Tags: plc

I've been tasked in designing logic for dorm rooms. The design of the dorm is that that two rooms share the one bathroom (roomL-door-bathroom-door-roomR). I'm having trouble designing logic for it. Here are the requirements:

- If a person from roomL enters, person from roomR is forbidden to enter.
- A person can't move between rooms through the bathroom.
- (Desired but optional) If a bathroom is occupied by person from roomL no one from roomL can enter.

Each door will have electromagnetic lock (normally open in case of emergency) so I can lock the door through software. I was thinking this:

1. Doors are normally unlocked. If a person opens the door from roomL, door from roomR will lock.
2. He would have, lets say, 30 seconds to press the occupied push button (timer is there to prevent people from leaving the door open).
3. After it's pressed both doors will be locked.
4. When the button is pressed again it will unlock the door from which the person came (PLC will remember the last door open).
5. When a person exits the room and closes the door it will unlock other room's door (again, 30 sec after pushing the button the doors will be unlocked).

Is this a good design?

**UPDATE**

So I've revamped the design and the logic that can be seen from the diagram bellow. I don't see any holes in this new design but a fresh pair of eyes couldn't hurt!

[image: Bathroom Diagram]

Comment: If the question does not belong here, please refer me to a site where I can ask this kind of question. Thank you!

Comment: On step 5, what stops the person opening and closing the exit door, but staying inside?  The other dorm door will then unlock, to which they will have access.

Comment: Yep, that's a problem. This needs more thought.

Comment: How do the dorm occupants normally unlock the corridor doors to get into their rooms? You are probably going to have to hook into this system somehow.

Comment: sounds like you need a room occupancy sensor, say PIR, in the bathroom, as well as door open/closed sensors. A door traffic sensor could be spoofed by two people entering, and one leaving (birds can be fooled into thinking a hide is unoccupied that way). However, PIR can be spoofed if you stand still enough.

Comment: @JackB They would unlock the door with their student card which would then be placed in a wall reader to turn on electricity and lights. We are also designing that system.

Comment: @Neil_UK I had thought of using manual locks on the inside of the room door, but since they are paying for all the fancy equipment i wish to use it for this system. Perhaps I'll make multiple offers and let the employer decide.

Comment: If this is a student dorm, then naturally inquisitive students will find any weaknesses in the system.  And drunk students will exploit them for laughs. And then someone will get upset and blame you.  I would not rely on PIR sensors as they are too easily fooled.

Comment: Yup you can't make it foolproof.. there is always a better fool round the corner.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.alianelectronics.com.au/sm108b-door-interlock-system.html and http://www.sdcsecurity.com/communicating-bathroom-systems.htm for examples of commercial systems.

Comment: My dorm with that '2 rooms 1 bathroom' arrangement just had inside and outside locks on both doors. True, your buddy could lock your bathroom door from the inside and then go out for the day, but that tended to only happen once. Mutually assured distruction.

Comment: @Neil_UK I have updated the question with a diagram of the new design that hopefully is bulletproof

Answer (score 2):

I think this procedure works better.

Both doors should stay closed so you need a door closer and alarm if it is stuck open. You should also have a motion sensor inside the bathroom. Handles on both sides of doors should actually be momentary switches.

1. both doors should be normally locked.
2. turning either entry handle should check toidy is not reserved by other room and if not unlock the door and reserve the room. An occupied courtesy light on the outside of both sides would be a nice feature.
3. On door closing door should lock.
4. Motion sensor now checked. If nobody is about, release reserved flag and light and return to state 1.
5. exit though entry door now enabled.
6. On try open exit door, unlock door and return to state 3.

**Issues:**

1. What happens when the power goes out?
2. Is through bathroom path part of the fire plan?
3. Have fun explaining to the girls that is a motion sensor and not a camera.
4. Some sort of Over-ride is needed to allow someone to enter in case occupant has a medical emergency. (which kind of defeats the whole purpose..)
5. Detecting occupied can be tricky, especially if there is a stall or area that is obscured (shower). Also motion alone can be a problem.. sit still on the can for a while. Been in a few washrooms that had motion activated lights go out while I was doing my business.. and waving arms did not help.

Comment: 1. The electromagnetic door lock _should_ be normally open in case of a an emergency like fire combined with power outage.
2. No, it is not
3.,5. The new solution solves the occupancy issue
4.  The _person in charge_ will have software from which he can control other areas of the dorm. We can implement an emergency override solution there.

Comment: @AntonioKovačević the issue with normally unlocked is both doors can be opened at the same time...

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. When the system is powered and idle, the door will be normally locked. But if the system looses power, in a case of a fire or some other emergency, the electromagnetic door should default to the unlocked state to allow the occupant to exit the bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not an answer directly, it might help you to improve your own requirements better.

I suggest instead of writing in text which is harder to check for problems, to make a diagram with states. This way probably you find flows much easier, also it makes testing easier because you know all states and events from one state to another.

Define states:

- DoorL: open/closed
- DoorR: open/closed

Events:

- Push button pressed
- Start timer
- 30 seconds elapsed

Also you might take the occupancy sensor into account according Neil_UK's comment as a state (occupied/not occupied) and events (start occupancy, end occupancy).

Comment: I think occupancy is a state, not an event. Start/end occupancy are events.

Comment: I meant indeed the last items you mentioned, but I adapted my answer, thanks.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers per your suggestion I've updated the question with a diagram of the new design.

Comment: Looks really good (I'm sure it helps you with testing/analyzing)... what I see is from Bathroom-Occupied, two events with push button S, that seems a bit strange to me. Normally in a state diagram, there's only one state active at the same time (although it is possible to have 'inner'  states.